# How to convert list array to float

Tags: python

I have an little endian list value in python, I get with serial line.

I get this value as a byte like this:

```
[0, 0, 52, 66]
```

How can I convert this 4 byte (little endian) value to float ?

Comment: can you provide the expected output for clarity?

Comment: You should take a look at the [struct module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the float is in IEEE754 format (which it very likely is), you can convert your list of numbers to a byte array and then use [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) to unpack it:

```
import struct
ba = bytes([0, 0, 52, 66])
print(struct.unpack('<f', ba)[0]) # prints 45.0
```

Comment: this is the answer i was looking for thanks.